# ¿Cómo agregar elementos XML en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de agregar elementos y atributos desde código... El primer elemento Reference lo agrega bien pero al tratar de agregar el segundo  me sale un error que dice :

> Elemento **Reference** mal formado.

Este es mi codigo :

```
   public  void FirmarXadesEPES(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 cert)
        {

            if (xmlDoc == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
            if (cert == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Cert");

            String keyInfoID = "keyinfoID";
            String signedPropertiestypeID = "SignedPropertiestypeID";
            String signatureID = "FacturaeSignatureID";

            XadesSignedXml signedXml = new XadesSignedXml(xmlDoc);
            signedXml.SigningKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = "";

            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            reference.AddTransform(env);
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

            // AQUI EL ERROR
            Reference keyInfoReference = new Reference();
            keyInfoReference.Uri = "#" + keyInfoID;
            env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            keyInfoReference.AddTransform(env);
            signedXml.AddReference(keyInfoReference);

            Reference signedProperiestypeReference = new Reference();
            signedProperiestypeReference.Uri = "#" + signedPropertiestypeID;
            signedProperiestypeReference.Type = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties";
            env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            reference.AddTransform(env);
            signedXml.AddReference(signedProperiestypeReference);

            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            keyInfo.Id = keyInfoID;
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

            QualifyingPropertiesType qualifyingProperties = new QualifyingPropertiesType();

            qualifyingProperties.Target = "#" + signatureID;
            qualifyingProperties.SignedProperties = new SignedPropertiesType();
            qualifyingProperties.SignedProperties.Id = signedPropertiestypeID;
            qualifyingProperties.SignedProperties.SignedSignatureProperties = new SignedSignaturePropertiesType();
            qualifyingProperties.SignedProperties.SignedSignatureProperties.SigningTime = DateTime.Today;
            qualifyingProperties.SignedProperties.SignedSignatureProperties.SignaturePolicyIdentifier = new SignaturePolicyIdentifierType();

            SignaturePolicyIdType signaturePolicyIdType = new SignaturePolicyIdType();
            signaturePolicyIdType.SigPolicyId =new ObjectIdentifierType();
            signaturePolicyIdType.SigPolicyId.Identifier=new IdentifierType();
            signaturePolicyIdType.SigPolicyId.Identifier.Value = "http://www.facturae.es/politica_de_firma_formato_facturae/politica_de_firma_formato_facturae_v3_1.pdf";
            signaturePolicyIdType.SigPolicyId.Description = "facturae31";

            signaturePolicyIdType.SigPolicyHash = new DigestAlgAndValueType();
            signaturePolicyIdType.SigPolicyHash.DigestMethod = new DigestMethodType2();
            signaturePolicyIdType.SigPolicyHash.DigestMethod.Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";
            signaturePolicyIdType.SigPolicyHash.DigestValue = Convert.FromBase64String("Ohixl6upD6av8N7pEvDABhEL6hM=");

            qualifyingProperties.SignedProperties.SignedSignatureProperties.SignaturePolicyIdentifier.Item = signaturePolicyIdType;

            //signedXml.AddQualifyingPropertiesObject(qualifyingProperties);
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo suelo preferir las clases del espacio de nombres System.Xml.Linq [System.Xml.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx). En este espacio, hay dos clases muy útiles: [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) y [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx). Ambas incorporan un método Add que permite añadirles un nuevo elemento XML como hijo. Si hijoXElement es el elemento que quieres añadirle, la instrucción es tan sencilla como:

padreXElement.Add(hijoXElement) en el caso de un elemento XML o

padreXDocument.Add(hijoXElement) en el caso de un documento XML.

Espero que mi consejo te sea útil.